# MySQL follow the change of the column

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is the following:

```
Name   Income   Date 
---------------------------------  
John    100     2014.03.03  
John    100     2014.03.04  
Mike    100     2014.03.04    
John    200     2014.03.04  
Martin  100     2014.03.04  
Mike    100     2014.03.05  
Mike    100     2014.03.05   
John    200     2014.03.05    
John    200     2014.03.05  
John    200     2014.03.05  
Martin  200     2014.03.05  
John    100     2014.03.05  
John    300     2014.03.05
```

And I would like the following output:

```
Name   Income   Date
---------------------------------
John    100     2014.03.03  
Mike    100     2014.03.04  
John    200     2014.03.04  
Martin  100     2014.03.04   
Martin  200     2014.03.05   
John    100     2014.03.05   
John    300     2014.03.05
```

So if John's value is 100 I'd like to get only once (the date doesn't matter it could be the newest or the oldest). But if the value changes (even to an earlier value) I'd like to write it to the output. How can I do that?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: No. For example John's income is 100 and the following 4 rows for John is also 100, I only want the first or, last one. (but only once). If it changes to 200 I'd like it in the output. And if it changes from 200 to anything else (even 100) I want it again in the output. Is it clear?

Comment: try `group by` clause with `name,income` and to detect the changed value, make a extra column named lets say "chnage". Now, if the value chnages, you make that column 1 else keep it 0.In this way, you can get the updated value too

Comment: Are there any methods to solve this problem without adding extra columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda wrong, but

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY name, income;
```

Or use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, income FROM table;
```

Comment: Thanks but Distinct isn't really the answer this time :/